# Reviewer asked me clarify a point – should I add it to manuscript or to the response to reviewer?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

A reviewer asked me to clarify one point:

> why was a triple marker offered to a 39 year old women? Is it a
> routine practice in your setting? Did we offer quadruple? Or was it
> not available? Please clarify this in the document.

I responded only by a comment, telling them that these are routine settings in our practice. So should I have added this info to the manuscript as well? Does that make any sense?

Comment: Add it to both if you aren't sure.

Answer (score 26):

Generally speaking - yes, the reviewer probably also expected it clarified in the paper, not just in the response letter. If it was unclear to this reviewer, it might also be unclear to readers (at least that's the line of thought behind such comments). If the reviewer believed this to be sufficiently unimportant that it does not have to be described in the paper, then why would they even bring up this point during review?

Comment: Can the reviewer accept my comment  without  other clarifications as I mentioned above   or it’s clearly he  will sent the paper back again ?

Comment: @YanniAmeer Why wouldn't you just add it to the manuscript? Your published paper is for other people to read, not just your reviewers.

Comment: @YanniAmeer - remember, your paper is the clearest to you since you wrote it. Just how clear it is to somebody else can vary a lot depending on how well it is written. If a reviewer has doubts about the clarity, then you should clarify in the text because likely somebody else (even less skilled in the field) will have difficulties following the text.

Comment: Actullay it wasn’t clear enough , he would ask me to add / merge it to the main manuscript,because my mansucript have limited word count . however ,I’m waiting for the decision

Comment: @YanniAmeer Of course they "can" - whether they care enough to recommend another revision because of this or not is impossible to know.

Comment: @YanniAmeer The reviewer **explicitly** asked you to clarify it in your manuscript. That's what "Please clarify this in the document" means. Note: such comments from reviewers *implicitly* mean clarify it in the reviewed document. The reviewer shouldn't need to be explicit about it being about a requested/suggested change to the reviewed paper. If they *didn't* mean that it should be clarified in the manuscript, then the reviewer either shouldn't have said anything or should have been explicit that the comment *wasn't* about making a change to the reviewed document.